# How to install selected version of Azure modules in the portal

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Hi am trying to install specific versions of Azure modules so that I can successfully create a runbook for automation. I have gone through the portal and searched for the module there but I only see the most up-to-date version. I know how to install specific versions via PowerShell, but it seems that is just for the PowerShell instance. I need to be able to install the modules so that I can use the cmdlets in my runbook.

Is there a way to do this? I am new to azure so I am still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following way to import specify module into your Automation account.

1.Import modules in the Azure portal

Go to your Automation account.
Under `Shared Resources`, select `Modules`.
**Select `Add a module`.**
Select the `.zip file` that contains **your module with specify version**.
Select OK to start to import process.
[image]
2.Import modules from the PowerShell Gallery

Go to `https://www.powershellgallery.com` and search for the **module with specify version** to import.
Under `Installation Options`, on the `Azure Automation` tab, select `Deploy to Azure Automation`. This action opens the Azure portal.

[image]

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-modules).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!